# how to append a backquote in java string

Tags: java

Someone please help me how to append a backquote in a string in java.
 I tried with String result="`"+value+"`";
I need to append the backquote before and after the string.

What is the correct way?

Answer (score 2):

You should scape `"` using `\"`

Eg:   `"\""+value+"\""`;

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/L6DmBZ) demo.

Edit: OP want to use backquote(```) so answer will be following and no need to scape.

```
"`"+value+"`"
```

[Ideone](http://ideone.com/GTIMwR) demo.

Comment: It's strange that your original answer was wrong yet you immediately got 2 upvotes...

Comment: note that OP means backquote( `\``) not double quote

Comment: @doogabides I was used ` \\ ` instead of  ` \ ` and i corrected it immediately. Sometimes voters may think same as I do. Any way wrong answers not have long life here.

Comment: @RuchiraGayanRanaweera I didn't see it too, until I view the question in edit mode :D

Comment: It works while appending a double quotes("). But I need to insert backquote(`)

Answer (score 1):

When we use literal strings in Java, we use the quote (") character to indicate the beginning and ending of a string. For example, to declare a string called myString, we could this :-

String myString = "this is a string";

But what if we wanted to include a quote (") character WITHIN the string. We can use the \ character to indicate that we want to include a special character, and that the next character should be treated differently. \" indicates a quote character, not the termination of a string.

```
public static void main (String args[])
    {
        System.out.println ("If you need to 'quote' in Java");
        System.out.println ("you can use single \' or double \" quote");
}
```

This allows us to include quote characters within a string.